# how to call Java method which returns any List from R Language?

Tags: java, r, rjava

How to call java method which returns list from R Language.

Comment: See this page: https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/calling-java-code-from-r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [rJava](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) package.

```
install.packages('rJava')
library(rJava)
.jinit()
jObj=.jnew("JClass")
result=.jcall(jObj,"[D","method1")
```

Here, `JClass` is a Java class that should be in your ClassPath environment variable, `method1` is a static method of `JClass` that returns `double[]`, `[D` is a JNI notation for a double array. See [that](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/calling-java-code-from-r/) blog entry for details.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: I downloaded the HelloJavaWorld package , I followed the steps by calling library(helloJavaWorld) which made it work. I am trying to call through your step normal class which I created through eclipse. But I am getting ClassNotFoundException .How can I make that class to be in classpath environment variable . I have set the classPath in environment variable which is pointing to  lib folder of jdk

Comment: Your ClassPath should have both JDK's \lib folder and folder with your compiled .jar file (or .class) split with ';'